# Iterating through the ethereum blockchain using Java

Tags: blockchain, ethereumj, java, leveldb

I am trying to iterate through the LevelDB in ethereum to see what data is stored in the blockchain. I have loaded the database and created in itr using [Dain's LevelDB](https://github.com/dain/leveldb) api, but I am having trouble pulling any keys from the blockchain. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I also made a [post earlier](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26990/loading-leveldb-in-java) about this toic.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the Dain's levelDB only uses .sst files, please use [fusesource's levelDB library](https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni).